# Target file name using file name expression in streamsets

Tags: streamsets

I am trying to load the data from Google cloud-bucket to Local file system using below:

My Origin (Google Cloud Storage) Properties:

- Common Prefix = /Target_Files/2019_12_02_Part1/
- Prefix Pattern = *SDC_11643212-5147-49ba-92e8-ba0308679000*

My Destination (Local FS) Properties:

- Data Format = Whole File
- File Name Expression = ${record:value('/fileInfo/sales')}.json

But, The target file is not generating as sales.json, It is created as `sdc-12ae0f4b-06ac-11ea-a26a-cf076a1f70a7_3d8447a7-19b6-4990-ac3b-daff4c4c2a7c`

I want to generate the simple target file name as "sales.json"

Could someone help to generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of things going on here:

1. Check **Files Prefix** on the Local FS **Output Files** tab - this is likely set to the default, `sdc-${sdc:id()}`, which is producing the filename you are seeing.
2. Use [Preview](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Data_Preview/DataPreview_Title.html) to check that the `/fileInfo/sales` field is actually set. This field is not set by the Google Cloud Storage origin, so I assume you are setting it elsewhere in the pipeline.

If you just want the output file to be `sales.json`, and not depend on anything in the whole file record, you can set **File Name Expression** to your desired filename.